# R data correlation, permutation of all variables without duplicates

Tags: r, math, statistics, permutation

I want to correlate each variable in given a data.frame in R by permutation. The set is for this example kept simple and it has 4 variables:

```
X<-data.frame("A"=rnorm(1e3),"B"=rnorm(1e3),"C"=rcauchy(1e3),"D"=rcauchy(1e3))
```

So what I want back is a data.frame with contains the correlation of each of this with each other. A result might be a data.frame with this columns:

```
A.B, A.C, ... B.C, B.D, ...
```

There should be no repeating, so A.A or things like B.D and D.B (duplicates) are not allowed.

Is the an apply function for that? How can this be done in a R typical convenient style?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
X<-data.frame("A"=rnorm(1e3),"B"=rnorm(1e3),"C"=rcauchy(1e3),"D"=rcauchy(1e3))
m <- cor(X)
m[lower.tri(m, diag = TRUE)] <- NA
library(reshape2)
(df <- na.omit(melt(m)))
#    Var1 Var2       value
# 5     A    B  0.05247314
# 9     A    C -0.04440715
# 10    B    C  0.01905053
# 13    A    D  0.01920278
# 14    B    D -0.02102680
# 15    C    D  0.02793279

transform(df, Var = paste(Var1, Var2, sep = "."), Var1 = NULL, Var2 = NULL)
#          value Var
# 5   0.05247314 A.B
# 9  -0.04440715 A.C
# 10  0.01905053 B.C
# 13  0.01920278 A.D
# 14 -0.02102680 B.D
# 15  0.02793279 C.D
```